# MYSQL Self-JOIN With Reduction

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a terrible MYSQL mental block and for the life of me, can't figure out this simple query. When I see the right answer, I'm sure I'll end-up kicking myself... One of those days.

*** FINGERS CROSSED *** :)

Ok, so don't laugh.

`Table Name: urls`

```
    id  hostname_id  url           user_id  
------  -----------  ------------  ----------------
     1           15  loc.com/xxx                  2
     2           15  loc.com/ab2                  2
     3           15  loc.com/cdf                  3
     4           15  loc.com/xx7                  1
     5           17  yax.com/21sv                 3
     6           17  yax.com/148g                 3
 ----------------------------------------------------
```

**`And This is the desired Query Result`**

```
hostname_id |   hostname_id_COUNT       |user_id_COUNT
-----------     ------------            ----------------
15              4                       3
17              2                       1
```

I've tried multiple ways like joins, group by's with counts. Personally, if it was up to my I'll use map/Reduce, but the database is fixed to mysql the solution has to MySql.

Could someone help me from this embarrassing mental block. :) And a huge THANK YOU! in advance for your time.

## Sample data  for the example I posted above.

```
CREATE TABLE `testing`.`urls` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `hostname_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

INSERT INTO `testing`.`urls` (`hostname_id`, `url`, `user_id`) VALUES ('15', 'loc.com/xxx', '2'); 
INSERT INTO `testing`.`urls` (`hostname_id`, `url`, `user_id`) VALUES ('15', 'loc.com/ab2', '2');  
INSERT INTO `testing`.`urls` (`hostname_id`, `url`, `user_id`) VALUES ('15', 'loc.com/cdf', '3');  
INSERT INTO `testing`.`urls` (`hostname_id`, `url`, `user_id`) VALUES ('15', 'loc.com/xx7', '1');  
INSERT INTO `testing`.`urls` (`hostname_id`, `url`, `user_id`) VALUES ('17', 'yax.com/21sv', '3'); 
INSERT INTO `testing`.`urls` (`hostname_id`, `url`, `user_id`) VALUES ('17', 'yax.com/148g', '3');
```

Comment: I guess that should be `hostname_id` 17 instead of 5 in your expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for an aggregation per hostname ID in combination with `COUNT DISTINCT`:

```
select
  hostname_id, 
  count(*) as hostname_id_count,
  count(distinct user_id) as user_id_count
from urls
group by hostname_id;
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much. And yes, I did kick myself really hard. It was ` count(distinct user_id) as user_id_count` that I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to show total count based on hostname & user.
Try this:

```
select
  hostname_id, 
  count(id) as total_count,
  user_id
from urls
group by hostname_id, user_id;
```